# Apache AGE - Postgres Crashes while looping through all the Children Oids

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have written this code to get all the childrens Oids in the Apache AGE file named `age_global_graph.c` in the function named `load_edge_hashtable`

```
child_edges_oid = find_inheritance_children(edge_label_table_oid, NoLock);
       
        //loop through all the child edges
        ListCell *lc1;
        foreach (lc1, child_edges_oid)
        {
            Oid child_edge_oid = lfirst_oid(lc1);
            
        }
```

Here the child_edges_oid gets all the children Oids and in the for loop I am trying to get the oid of each child. But when I run this, my postgres crashes.

What I want is that I should be able to get the Oids of all the children

Answer (score 0):

Check if `find_inheritance_children()` function is returning a valid list. This function might be returning NULL or invalid data, which can cause a crash when you attempt to iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

You passed the 'NoLock' parameter to the `find_inheritance_children`. It may possibly cause concurrency issues if multiple transactions access the data concurrently. Try changing the lock to ensure data consistency.